# How can we transfer data object from one component to another component without using params, queryparams and services in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I don't want to use any params, queryparam or any service method. Is there any way to transfer a data object using routing in Angular 2?

Comment: AngularJS or Angular 2?

Comment: Communicate from parent to child using input properties, and from child to parent using EventEmitters. Services is also valid method ... not sure why you want to avoid that (are you aware that you can host services on component level instead of module level?). Also, Redux (ngrx-store) is a possiblity